# Merge or Concat Dataframes using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, merge

Simplified. I have 2 dataframes that I would like to merge/concatenate/join together into one using the following scenario as framework.

df1 looks like

```
              C1              C2       C3
0   1659712000.0    1659712000.0    YQHDK
1   5797862000.0    5797862000.0    YQHJW
2    846369000.0     846369000.0    YQHMF
3    508287000.0     508287000.0    YQHRV
4    878002000.0     878002000.0    YQHVT
5            NaN    5178784324.0    YQHRM
```

While df2 looks like

```
       C3             C1
0   YQHRM   2362463460.0
```

What I desire is to fill in the `NaN` value as follows:

```
              C1              C2       C3
0   1659712000.0    1659712000.0    YQHDK
1   5797862000.0    5797862000.0    YQHJW
2    846369000.0     846369000.0    YQHMF
3    508287000.0     508287000.0    YQHRV
4    878002000.0     878002000.0    YQHVT
5   2362463460.0    5178784324.0    YQHRM
```

I've tried using `df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='C3)`, but this creates two `C1` columns, a `C1_x` and a `C1_y`.

I've also tried using `pd.concat([df1, df2])` but this results in two rows for `YQHRM'`.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [`combine_first()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df1.set_index('C3')
df2.set_index('C3')    
df2.combine_first(df1)

                 C1          C2
C3                             
YQHDK  1.659712e+09  1659712000
YQHJW  5.797862e+09  5797862000
YQHMF  8.463690e+08   846369000
YQHRM  2.362463e+09  5178784324
YQHRV  5.082870e+08   508287000
YQHVT  8.780020e+08   878002000
```

`df2.reset_index()` will revert the `index` back to `column`.